# From PNG to DOT conversion using Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have coded a parser in Python using NetworkX that generates a dot file.
Using Graphviz I'm able to convert the dot file to other format correctly, for example from dot to png:
`dot -Tpng input.dot > output.png`

I was wondering if it is possible to do the reverse way, converting from png to dot, but I'm facing an error:
`Error: output.png: syntax error in line 1 near 'ëPNG'`

This is the sentence I have tried (and from other file formats too):
`dot -Tdot output.png > output_cmd.dot`

Comment: Converting from a pixel bitmap to a logical structure or even "just" vector formats is a very difficult task and not implemented by GraphViz, as far as I know: [A Blog about techniques for converting images to graphs](https://www.yworks.com/blog/projects-optical-graph-recognition)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the link is very interesant. Well, my way of thinking is if you can parse a .dot and create a .png or .json, it could be possible to be done in the reverse way if both are created with the same tool

Comment: just because a cow can produce milk and cow-shit from grass, doesn't mean it can do the reverse thing :-D  - bitmaps are a completely different concept.

Answer (score 0):

Hope springs eternal - but no, Graphviz can't do this.

1. If your output file was SVG format, it would be somewhat easier to convert back to dot format (though not trivial)
2. If I was going to attempt png->dot, I'd try using netpbm, Imagemagick, and some OCR software.